# Insert array in ONE field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to insert an array in ONE field in mysql database using PHP ..

this is work fine :

HTML :

```
anotherField :<input type="text"  name="anotherField" />

fax :<input type="text"  name="f[]" />
email :<input type="text"  name="f[]" />
phone :<input type="text"  name="f[]" />
```

PHP (I use CodeIgniter frame) :

```
<?php
    function addCustomRow($tableName)
    {

    $arr = $this->input->post('f');
    $field = implode("|", $arr);

        $data = array(
        'anotherField'          => $this->input->post('anotherField'),
        'field'             => $field
        );

        $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
    }
?>
```

and I get data in mysql like this

```
fax|email|phone
```

**BUT ..**

My question is .. I want many arrays in the same field .. Like this :

```
fax|email|phone :br: fax|email|phone :br: fax|email|phone ..
```

I tried some thing like this  :

Html :

```
First array :
fax :<input type="text" class="inp" name="f[0][0]" />
email :<input type="text" class="inp" name="f[0][1]" />
phone :<input type="text" class="inp" name="f[0][2]" />

Second array :
fax :<input type="text" class="inp" name="f[1][0]" />
email :<input type="text" class="inp" name="f[1][1]" />
phone :<input type="text" class="inp" name="f[1][2]" />
```

PHP :

```
<?php
    function addCustomRow($tableName)
    {

    $arr = $this->input->post('f[]');
    $field = implode(":br:", $arr);

        $data = array(
        'anotherField'          => $this->input->post('anotherField'),
        'field'             => $field
        );

        $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
    }
?>
```

but it says Wrong [ Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion  ]
and I get data in mysql like this

```
array :br: array
```

**EDIT :**

I want to do that like this way because I have a Categories Table ..
and each cat has own details ( fields ) .. so when I add new cat I just do some thing like this

```
       name of cat : <input type="text"  name="name" />

   <!-- Fields -->
    Fields //

    Field 1 :
    title of the filde : <input type="text"  name="f[0][0]" />
    type : <input type="text"  name="f[0][1]" /> <!-- 1= text , 2= select , 3= textarea ..  -->
    default value : <textarea rows="8" cols="20" name="f[0][2]"> </textarea> <!-- if select type write value1::value2::value3  ... -->



Field 2 :
title of the filde : <input type="text"  name="f[1][0]" />
type : <input type="text"  name="f[1][1]" /> <!-- 1= text , 2= select , 3= textarea ..  -->
default value : <textarea rows="8" cols="20" name="f[1][2]"> </textarea> <!-- if select type write value1::value2::value3  ... -->

Field 3 :
title of the filde : <input type="text"  name="f[2][0]" />
type : <input type="text"  name="f[2][1]" /> <!-- 1= text , 2= select , 3= textarea ..  -->
default value : <textarea rows="8" cols="20" name="f[2][2]"> </textarea> <!-- if select type write value1::value2::value3  ... -->
```

and I can add any number of fields here ..

in database I want data inserted like this :

```
[nameOfBook|1|anyName :br: noOfPages|1|anyNo ]
```

and in the other cat like this for example :

[colorOfcar|2|red::black::green :br: price|1|anyPrice ]

any help ?

thanks in advance ..

---

@Justin Johnson

thanks for your answer, but it doesnt work.
I have to use $data var to insert all the data but I use you answer like this

```
function addCustomRow($tableName)
{

    $data = array(
        'name'          => $this->input->post('name'),
        'fields'            => serialize($this->input->post('f[]'))
        );

    $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
}
```

and I get data mysqyl like this ( b:0; ) !!

//

@Suku thanks .. I have used it before asking but I did not know how .. How can I use it in my case here ? ..

@Alex

because I have table named (categories) and every cat has own fields like :

```
carsCat >
  type :
  color:
  details:

BooksCat >
nameOfbook:
writer:
numberOfpage:
```

and so on ..
I find this way the Best way maybe in my case .. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with a small trick :)
I just add one heddin input with value (:br:) , and keep all names of inputs equal (f[]) .. like this :

**HTML :**

```
field out of the array :
anotherField :<input type="text"  name="name" />

Field 1 :
title of the field : <input type="text"  name="f[]" />
type : <input type="text"  name="f[]" /> <!-- 1= text , 2= select , 3= textarea ..  -->
value : <textarea rows="8" cols="20" name="f[]"> </textarea> <!-- if select type write value1::value2::value3  ... -->
<input type="hidden" name="f[]" value=":br:" />

Field 1 :
title of the field : <input type="text"  name="f[]" />
type : <input type="text"  name="f[]" /> <!-- 1= text , 2= select , 3= textarea ..  -->
value : <textarea rows="8" cols="20" name="f[]"> </textarea> <!-- if select type write value1::value2::value3  ... -->
<input type="hidden" name="f[]" value=":br:" />
```

**PHP :**

```
function addCustomRow($tableName)
{
$arrF1 = $this->input->post('f');
$f = implode("|", $arrF1);

$data = array(
    'name'  => $this->input->post('name'),
        'fields'    => $f
    );

$this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
```

}

now I get data in mysql like this :

```
titleOffield|type|value|:brr:|titleOffield|type|value|:brr:
```

for example :

```
nameOfBook|1|writeTheName|:Br:|NoOfPages|1|value|:br:|
```

Then I can return the data from mysql database easily like this :
(I use Smarty ! )

**Output**

```
  {assign var=fieldsBr value=":br:|"|explode:$r.values} <!-- exploade :br: -->

    {foreach from=$fieldsBr item=ff}
    {assign var=f value="|"|explode:$ff} <!-- exploade | -->
    {$f[0]} :  <b>{$f[2]}</b>  <br />  <!-- title of field :  the value  <br />  -->
    {/foreach}
```

** Notice I use 2 explode here One for (:br:|) and the other for (|) ..

Thanks any way for your help ..

Ahmad ..

Answer (score 3):

To store an array in one field, just [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it. When you need to access the array from the database [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it.

Comment: serialize and unserialize will do the trick and as Justin Johnson also mentioned it's also good to normalize them

Comment: thanks .. I have used it before asking but I did not know how .. How can I use it in my case here ?

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, I would suggest that you try to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table scheme a little more.  Storing multiple, multiple values in one field is going to cause many headaches.  Perhaps, something like this:

[image]

In this scheme, the `contact_information` table is associated with the `person` table by storing an ID (foreign reference) to a person row.  This way, you can have as many contact entries for any given person, without having to cram an array of data into one field.

---

At any rate, to solve your problem as it is, try serializing the data before you insert it into the DB.

```
function addCustomRow($tableName) {    
    $data = array(
        'anotherField' => $this->input->post('anotherField'),
        'field'        => serialize($this->input->post('f[]'))
    );

    $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
}
```

Edit: updated to address comment.

Comment: thanks for your answer .. umm but it dosnt work ..
I have to use $data var to insert all the data but I use you answer like this

    function addCustomRow($tableName)
    {

        $data = array(
     'name'    => $this->input->post('name'),
     'fields'    => serialize($this->input->post('f[]'))
  );

        $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
    }

and I get data mysqyl like this ( b:0; ) !!

Comment: Sorry about that, copy and pasted into the wrong place.  I've updated my answer with the corrected code.

Comment: thanks .. I use your new code but also it says wrong ( 


A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'anotherField' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `cats` (`anotherField`, `field`) VALUES (0, 'b:0;')


)

Comment: oh sorry ! .. I change the name of the field to (name) , the data is inserted but I get that ( b:0; ) in my field :(

Answer (score 2):

You may need to use the functions serialize() and unserialize() as the following:

```
$string_from_array = serialize($array);
```

and when you need to restore the array:

```
$array= unserialize($string_from_array);
```

see this for more info : http://www.wpfasthelp.com/insert-php-array-into-mysql-database-table-row-field.htm

Answer (score 0):

*INSERTING ARRAY VALUES FROM FORM INTO DATABASE*

```
function addRecord($Table){
        global $connection; // database connection
        extract($Table);

        $entry_date = date('Y-m-d');

        for($i=0; $i< count($project_id); $i++)
        {

            $sql="INSERT INTO expenses(type_id,project_id,amount,exp_date,entry_date,comments,entry_name)
              values('$type_id[$i]','$project_id[$i]','$amount[$i]','$exp_date[$i]','$entry_date','$comments[$i]','$_SESSION[emp_name]')";

            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        }
```